# ¿Como contar lineas dentro de una clausula?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Quiero hacer una búsqueda para saber la lista de facturas que tienen más de 18 líneas de factura.

Las tablas que tengo son las siguientes:

| tb_invoice | tb_company | tb_lines |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Code – foreign key company | Code – primary key | Invoice_id |
| Invoice_id – primary key | Name | Line_id – primary key |
| Invoice_no | Address | Line_num |
| Cust_no - foreign key customer | City | Item |
| Site_id- foreign key site | Country | Description |
| Payednet_amount | Last_updated_by | Net_amount |
| Iva_amount | Last_update_date | Iva_amount |
| Tot_amount |  | Last_updated_by |
| Last_updated_by |  | Last_update_date |
| Last_update_date |  |  |

El código que he planteado es el siguiente:

```
SELECT i.invoice_no, i.cust_no, c.co_name, l.line_num
FROM erp.tb_invoice AS i, erp.tb_company AS c, erp.tb_lines AS l
WHERE l.line_num>18
    AND l.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
    AND i.co_code = c.co_code
ORDER BY l.line_num DESC, c.co_name;
```

El error está en la cláusula `WHERE`, ya que debo contarlas y `WHERE l.line_num>18` no es correcto porque puede haber alguna línea borrada, pero no sé cómo hacer una búsqueda dentro de otra, que creo que es lo que debería hacer, verdad? Creo que debería

No sé si sería algo parecido a lo que indico a continuación. No tengo claro cómo asociar la cuenta y la búsqueda:

```
SELECT i.invoice_no, i.cust_no, c.co_name, l.line_num
FROM erp.tb_invoice AS i, erp.tb_company AS c, erp.tb_lines AS l
WHERE l.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
      AND i.co_code = c.co_code
HAVING COUNT (*)= (SELECT COUNT (*)
                    FROM erp.tb_lines AS r
                    GROUP BY r.invoice_id);
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando [`COUNT()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-count-function/), [`GROUP BY`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-group-by/) y [`HAVING`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-having/) podes lograrlo así:

```sql
SELECT 
    i.invoice_no,
    i.cust_no,
    c.co_name,
    COUNT(l.line_id) AS total_lines
FROM erp.tb_invoice AS i
    LEFT JOIN erp.tb_company AS c
        ON i.co_code = c.co_code
    LEFT JOIN erp.tb_lines AS l
        ON i.invoice_id = l.invoice_id
GROUP BY i.invoice_no, i.cust_no, c.co_name
HAVING COUNT(l.line_id) > 18;
```

Comment: muchas gracias. Entiendo el planteamiento y la verdad que así parece más simple de lo que pretendía hacer. De todas formas, me sale un error ```ERROR:  no existe la columna «total_lines»
LINE 6: HAVING total_lines > 18;```, pero no entiendo por qué si en el ```SELECT``` está definido ya ```total_lines``` Gracias!

Comment: @IñigoCatalánEchave, ahi lo corregí. Se me olvida que PostgreSQL no soporta alias en el `HAVING`

Comment: genial, he hecho ese mismo cambio, pero he tenido que añadir algunas variables más en el ```GROUP BY```. Supongo que con valores de las tablas se puede comprobar y de la forma en que planteo la duda no es posible. En todo caso, parece que ya sirve!